# MySQL PHP JSON null text

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, utf-8

I found a problem with some results of a search on a DB. When, some fields have extra characters like "ü", the field return as null so it appear as null on the search. My code is like this:
the php Script

```
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PRODFAR WHERE ARTI LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['search']."%'");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
```

the JSON PARSER constructor:

```
public class JsonParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject json_data = null;
    static String result = "";

    // constructor
    public JsonParser() {
    }

    public  JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, String url) {

        //http post this will keep the same way as it was (it's important to do not forget to add Internet access to androidmanifest.xml
        InputStream is = null;
        String result ="";
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response that we receive from the php file into a String()
        try{


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a Json object
        try {
            //json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return Json String
        return jArray;

    }    
}
```

any hint of how I can solve this?

update: as long as I cannot pass it with JSON, because it only admits UTF-8 characters. I think that one of the possible solutions is to convert the text through PHP into UTF-8 encoding archive, and the other is to use an alternative to JSON that supports other encodings. so I would like to try the first one. so if any know a good algorithm to covert the encoding of a text to UTF-8 using PHP will help to. Also other hints or tips of possible directions to find a solution are welcome please comment on this post any Idea is welcome

**SOLVED**
I solved it encoding it to UTF-8, it changed my characters like "ü" to something like u\000f, but the java editor show it as iso-8859-1 like Ü when it's showed on the screen. The edited PHP code have the following lines after the query:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PRODFAR WHERE ARTI LIKE '%$search1%'");
        while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
              $e['ARTI'] = utf8_encode ( $e['ARTI'] );
              $e['DESC'] = utf8_encode ( $e['DESC'] );
              $e['PRESENT'] = utf8_encode ( $e['PRESENT'] );   
                $output[]=$e;
        }
        print(json_encode($output));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only support UTF8. So try using utf8_encode() / utf8_decode() for conversion.

Comment: do you know if there is an option on MySQL to encode the data with UTF-8 non Case Sensitive. that is also compatible with JSON?

Comment: I'd like to keep my strings smaller and not escape everything blindly for UTF-8. Is there a way I can replace non-UTF8 chars with their UTF8 equivalents/closest replacements? Also how would utf8_enode affect my MySQL WHERE statements, which I have to encode my conditions as well?

Answer (score 0):

At first blush, I'd guess it as an encoding issue. Make sure your tables are UTF-8 and also that your views are the same.

Also: Please don't put `$_REQUEST` data directly into your SQL. That will come back to haunt you.

Comment: I've already changed the encoding to utf-8 bin on MySQL, but now I have problems, because the query distinct and "a" of an "A", so I hava less results is there a utf-8 encoding on MySQL that doesn't distinct uppercase and lower case letters?

Comment: @PedroTeran, use only utf-8, without the bin part

Comment: Thanks I used UTG-8_unicode as long as phpmyadmin does not let me select only UTF-8 that is also inependent from upper and lower cases, but when I perform the search through android I'm still getting null on the especial characters